# How to find duplicates in list of lists?

Tags: python, list, sorting, syntax

I have a list of key binds in a class like so:

```
self.key_bind_list = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["SHIFT", "NUM6", "NUM7"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
```

*in this case a duplicate should be detected by the sublists `["A", "B"]`, but not by `["A", "B"]` and `["A", "B", "C"]`

And I'd like to check if there are any duplicates on the main list (assuming that the keys within each sublist are uniques, order is not important, and I don't need to know which ones that aren't unique)

I've tried using the **set** method in the following:

```
if(len(self.key_bind_list) != len(set(self.key_bind_list))):
```

Which gave me a `unhashable type: 'list'` error.

Comment: are all sublists to be the same length?

Comment: No, they can contain from one key to any number of keys

Comment: `[set(x) for x in self.key_bind_list]` then you can compare

Comment: could you add an example of duplicate that should be detected?

Comment: so when you say order doesn't matter you mean a something like ["a","b"] and ["b", "a"] should be considered a duplicate?

What would a duplicate on the main list look like?

Comment: exactly, a duplicate in this case should result from two sublists having the same length and the same characters, in any given order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you *just* want to check if there are duplicates, and print out which sublists contain duplicates, you could use an approach with a list that contains `set` elements, such as so:

```py
key_bind_list = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["SHIFT", "NUM6", "NUM7"], ["B", "A"], ["A", "B", "C"]]

seen = []

for i, sublist in enumerate(key_bind_list):
    s = set(sublist)
    if s in seen:
        print(f'index {i}: there are duplicates in {sublist}')
    seen.append(s)
```

Output:

```
index 3: there are duplicates in ['B', 'A']
```

---

To just return a `bool` value if *any* sublist in a list is a duplicate (regardless of order) of another sublist, you could do something like this:

```py
def has_duplicates(L: list[list]) -> bool:
    seen = []

    for sublist in L:
        s = set(sublist)
        if s in seen:
            return True
        seen.append(s)

    return False


print(has_duplicates(key_bind_list))
```

Comment: I've edited the question again, in your solution, it seems the content of the sublists resulted in duplicates with other sublists (added example)

Comment: edited the question too, looks like it should fit the critieria hopefully

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter`. It fits well to model multisets. To bypass the `unhashable type` error a cast to `tuple` is needed but it makes the match **sensible to the sublists' ordering!**

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["SHIFT", "NUM6", "NUM7"], ["A", "B"]]

c = Counter(map(tuple, lst))

for k, v in c.items():
    if v > 1:
        print(k, v)
```

---

By checking all pairs with a set-equality criteria, i.e. all terms are equals upto to a certain ordering:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["SHIFT", "NUM6", "NUM7"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "B", "C"]]

for s1, s2 in combinations(map(set, lst), 2):
   if s1 == s2:
      print(s1)
#{'A', 'B'}
```

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35811225/10237506) post quite informative. essentially, looks like a `frozenset` might be hashable, as it is not mutable, unlike a set.

Comment: The change required in your post could be: `Counter(map(frozenset, lst))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
len(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in L])) != len(L)
```

Return `True` means there is duplicates in list of lists.

- Output:

  ```
  >>> L = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["SHIFT", "NUM6", "NUM7"], ["A", "B"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
  >>> print(len(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in L])) != len(L))
  True

  >>> L = [['A', 'B'], ['C'], ['SHIFT', 'NUM6', 'NUM7'], ['A', 'B', 'C']]
  >>> print(len(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in L])) != len(L))
  False

  >>> L = [["A", "B"], ["C"], ["SHIFT", "NUM6", "NUM7"], ["B", "A"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
  >>> print(len(set([tuple(sorted(x)) for x in L])) != len(L))
  True
  ```